# Calling Other Classes' Instance Method from Class Method? (Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, static-methods

I have the following method in a class named "Item". As you can see, getImage is a class/static method, but I want it to return an instance method from a DIFFERENT class (Item Instance). I don't see why it is not working?

```
+(UIImage*)getImage:(int)itemNumber {
    UIImage *image = [ItemInstance getImage:itemNumber];
    return image;
}
```

It tells me that the class method +getImage cannot be found in ItemInstance, but I am trying to call the instance method -getImage, not the class method +getImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call an instance method, you have to have an instance:

```
+ (UIImage*)getImage:(int)itemNumber {
    ItemInstance *anInstance = [[ItemInstance alloc] init];

    UIImage *image = [anInstance getImage:itemNumber];

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I did that... Stupid mistake. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
+(UIImage*)getImage:(int)itemNumber {
     ItemInstance *obj = [[[ItemInstance alloc]init] autorelease];
     UIImage *image = [obj getImage:itemNumber];
     return image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The other guy provided a slightly more detailed answer, but yours was right too and I appreciate it.